# Migration of GUI extensions from Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5. Is it fully backwards compatible?

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions, web8.5

I can't find a lot in Tridion Docs regarding GUI extensions. Are there any known issues migrating from 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5? Thank you in adavance

Answer (score 4):

There is a very extensive topic in the SDL Web 8.5 documentation regarding GUI extensions: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D, including a [SDL Web 8.5 GUI API reference](https://sdl.dist.sdlmedia.com/distributions/?o=E2964228-FFA8-4BF2-8BD9-B103ABC13576).

With regards to API changes, there are the following topics:

- GUI API delta compared to SDL Web 8 -
  http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-A79A03DF-48C2-484C-B0D4-C41FF894E827
- Backwards compatibility in Content Manager Explorer -
  http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9A4F45A5-E933-4AD0-9C3A-486E80135F54
- Deprecated GUI API utilities (SDL Web 8) - http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-6F63CD65-5C0E-4B06-AD66-48E9B6D9A946

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some of the Tridion Controls namespaces has been changed in SDL Web 8.5 like below,

so, in C# we need to recompile the UI Extension dll's

`using Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Controls;` (Used to be Tridion.Controls earlier)

`using Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Pages.PropertiesBox;`

as well as in the UI Extension javascript namespace references,

1. `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Pages.PropertiesBox.DrillDownListPropertyPanel`
2. `initialize` event has been renamed to `_initialize`

So, recompilation and namespace adjustments are required to get the UI Extensions working with SDL Web 8.5