# How to disable translation property based on Bundle Type?

Tags: gui-extensions, web8.5, translation-manager

I have a new CME requirement to disable the "translate" item from menu based on Bundle Scheme(Bundle Type) using CME GUI.

**Requirement Scenario 1 :**

When the user select the Publish_Bundle(Bundle) -- > right click  -- > BluePrinting -- > translate(Enable)

**Requirement Scenario 2 :**
When the user select the Expiry_Bundle(Bundle) -- > right click  -- > BluePrinting -- > translate(Disable)

**Bundle Type:**

1. Publish_Bundle(translation enable)
2. Expiry_Bundle(translation disable)

   Expiry_Bundle

**Step1 : When the authors Creating Bundle with Bundle Type is "expiry_bundle"**

[image]

**Step2 : if the Bundle Type is "expiry_bundle" ? It should be able to disable the "Translate".**

[image]

**Looking for solutions and ideas.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response.

> Final I implemented the translation menu item disable logic using CME GUI extension.

[image]
[image]

** extension and code below:**

**editor.config** : create a commandextensions and commandset.

```
<ext:commandextensions>
          <ext:commands>     
            <ext:command name="Translate" extendingcommand="SecureTranslate" />
          </ext:commands>
          <ext:dependencies>
            <cfg:dependency>SDLWeb.Resources.SecureCommands</cfg:dependency>
          </ext:dependencies>
</ext:commandextensions>


<cfg:commandset id="SDLWeb.Commands.SecureCommands">
      <cfg:command name="SecureTranslate" implementation="SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate" />
      <cfg:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>SDLWeb.Resources.SecureCommands</cfg:dependency>
      </cfg:dependencies>
</cfg:commandset>
```

****Secure.js:**(Create a JS file and add below code for _isAvailable,_isEnabled, _execute)**

```
    SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate = function (name) {
        Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate");
        this.addInterface("SDLWeb.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Commands.CommandBase", [name || "SecureTranslate"]);
    };

SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate = function (name) {
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate");
    this.addInterface("SDLWeb.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Commands.CommandBase", [name || "SecureTranslate"]);
};


SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate.prototype._isAvailable = function (selection, pipeline) {

    var itemTitle = "";
    var items = selection.getItems();
    if (items.length != 1) {
        return false;
    }  
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var itemId = selection.getItem(i);
        var item = $models.getItem(itemId);

      if (item.isLoaded() == false) {
           item.load();            
      }
      if (item.isLoaded(true) && Tridion.Type.isFunction(item.getMetadataSchemaId))
      {
            var schemaId = item.getMetadataSchemaId();
            var itemInfo = $models.getItem(schemaId);
            itemTitle = itemInfo.getStaticTitle();          
      }       
       if (item) {
            if (item.getItemType() == $const.ItemType.VIRTUAL_FOLDER) {              
                if (itemTitle !== "Publish_Bundle") {
                    if (pipeline) {
                        pipeline.stop = true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};

/*
*Checks whether to enable / disable the extension 
*/
SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate.prototype._isEnabled = function (selection, pipeline) {
    if (pipeline) {
        pipeline.stop = true;
    }
    return this._isAvailable(selection, pipeline);
};
/*
* default implementation
*/
SDLWeb.Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate.prototype._execute = function (selection, pipeline) {
    if (pipeline) {
        pipeline.stop = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Thanks for the update.

There's nothing out of the box here for you. I'd suggest you look at a GUI extension. I'd suggest you ensure that the logic is flexible enough to support future bundle names (or these titles being updated) by way of a simple config file - also ensure that your logic that "no-one" can send these for translation is solid - otherwise you may also want to add specific user groups being switched on/off also.

Take a look at the [SDL Web8.5 documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D). If you've done GUI Extensions in previous versions of Tridion then [this TREX response](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16913/migration-of-gui-extensions-from-tridion-2013-sp1-to-web-8-5-is-it-fully-backwa) by Bart may also help.

If you're new to GUI extensions then you should consider utilising the [Alchemy Framework](https://www.alchemywebstore.com/help/for-users/category/introduction/about-a4t) to support rapid development - you'll see plenty of tutorials etc. from John Winter on [TridionDeveloper.com](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/?s=alchemy&submit=Search) or just Google the heck out of it.

Comment: I try to disable the "translate" item from the menu based on the selected bundle type schema.

Comment: Can you edit the question by adding how you tried to disable the translate option? Was it through a GUI extension? And if so can you describe what didn't work in the GUI extension?

Comment: added the requirement scenario and it`s CME GUI Extensions.