# Publication Publishing Indicator for Publish and Expiry Workflows

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion

We have one of the CME enhancement requirement to have "Publication Locations" field in Bundle Info tab which would provide details on the bundle as to which publication the bundle will publish out/unpublish from .

[image]

Any suggestions/ideas how to do it?

Comment: GUI extension using the Anguilla framework. What have you tried? Did you see the docs?

Comment: So far I haven't tried anything. I want to get the publish instruction data from the workflow the bundle is a part of. Is it possible using any API ?

Comment: I have gone through the SDL Web 8.5 documentation, but I couldn't find how to add new control/field to existing Tab. The documentation talks only about extending Tabs - Add a tab to a dialog. Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this. Also once I add the new field, I need to show the publication names to which the bundle will be published to. How can I get the publish instruction data from the bundle workflow?

Answer (score 2):

As this obviously isn't out of the box then you will need to write a GUI Extension.

My post here may offer some starting points: [How to disable translation property based on Bundle Type?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/how-to-disable-translation-property-based-on-bundle-type/17639#17639)

I would also recommend you confirm what you've tried/read/thought about thus far and I can add more detail to this response.

Some simple questions come to mind immediately which makes me think there could be a lot more detail in here.

- are you expecting the resolving to happen every time someone opens the bundle? what if there are 500 components in that bundle?
- have you considered link resolving in here to be certain what pages will be published/unpublished

There are a lot more challenges with this but we should first understand what you've already thought about so advisors don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I'm wondering if the link to your post is enough of an answer (it should just be a lik, but also an extract of it in that case), or whether this is simply a comment on the question, with a suggestion to edit it?

Comment: That's a fair comment Bart - I've added a little more definition in the response - the problem is that there's limited space/formatting for it to be a useful comment. If you/moderators feel simply putting a link in as a comment would suffice - then let me know and I'll move it accordingly.

Comment: It's not so much the moderators, everybody with enough reputation can moderate here, so I'm just bringing it out there for the rest to think about, nobody has flagged your answer yet, so I'm not going to act yet either.