# Pages and Components are not loading after GUI Extension Web 8.1

Tags: web8, cme, gui-extensions, content-manager

I have implemented a GUI Extension in Web 8.1 to add new column in DashboardView for last published date. The functionality is working fine but after implementation, when I open CMS Pages and Components are stuck in loading state.

Could not found any error log in `core.log` and event viewer log.

Refer Below screen short.

[image]

[image]

Note: I have deployed same extension on Web 8.5 and it's working fine there but not working on client server Web 8.1.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated

Console error log for page and component.

[image]

[image]

Editor.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
               xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
                             xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
               xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">

  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters />
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.Model" merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.DomainModelProcessor" merge="always">
        <cfg:domainmodel name="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.Model">
          <cfg:fileset>
            <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/ExtendedPage.js</cfg:file>
            <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/ExtendedComponent.js</cfg:file>
          </cfg:fileset>
          <!-- <cfg:dependencies>
            <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
            <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency> -->
          <!--<cfg:dependency>Example.UiCoreService.Editor.Base</cfg:dependency> -->
          <!-- </cfg:dependencies> -->
          <cfg:services />
        </cfg:domainmodel>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>
  <definitionfiles />

  <extensions>
    <ext:dataextenders>
      <ext:dataextender name="MyGuiDataExtender" type="CustomDataExtender.GuiDataExtender,CustomDataExtender">
        <ext:description>
          Shows extra info
        </ext:description>
      </ext:dataextender>
    </ext:dataextenders>
    <ext:modelextensions>
      <cfg:itemtypes>
        <cfg:itemtype id="tcm:16" implementation="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent" />
        <cfg:itemtype id="tcm:64" implementation="Com.Tridion.PS.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage" />
      </cfg:itemtypes>
    </ext:modelextensions>
    <ext:editorextensions>
      <ext:editorextension target="CME">
        <ext:editurls/>
        <ext:listdefinitions/>
        <ext:taskbars/>
        <ext:commands/>
        <ext:commandextensions/>
        <ext:contextmenus/>
        <ext:lists>
          <ext:add>
            <ext:extension name="CustomColumnExtender" assignid="CustomDataColumnExtender">
              <ext:listDefinition>
                <ext:selectornamespaces/>
                <ext:columns>
                  <column xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/List" id="CustomData" type="data"  title="LastPublished" selector="@ExtendedInfo" translate="String"/>
                </ext:columns>
              </ext:listDefinition>
              <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="DashboardView" />
              </ext:apply>
            </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
        </ext:lists>
        <ext:tabpages/>
        <ext:toolbars/>
        <ext:ribbontoolbars/>
      </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
  </extensions>
 <commands/>
  <contextmenus />
  <localization />
  <settings>
    <defaultpage/>
    <!-- /Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage> -->
    <navigatorurl/>
    <!-- /Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl> -->
    <editurls/>
    <listdefinitions />
    <itemicons />
    <theme>
      <path>/Theme/</path>
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration>
      <clientconfiguration/>
    </customconfiguration>
  </settings>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: The JS file for your GUI extension might cause the issue. It's executing some code which is preventing the content loading. Please check your code in JS file

Comment: Please check console for any JS related error.

Comment: Please check editior.config and share the console error log.

Comment: To enable trace on the CMS and see if there are any errors

Comment: i think it`s editior.configuration issue. please check all reference.

Comment: @SudhakarRao I have updated my Question.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the error stack trace it's failing because of checking XPM settings on a component view. So a good question would be: Why is your component page loading SiteEdit page view scripts? And do you get the same error on a page view?

Comment: No i did not get this error on Page and some of the component are opened correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below namespace difference in sdl tridion 2013 and SDL WEB.

***Changes in JavaScript namespaces***

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the colors imply in your screenshot? @BartKoopman also sums up a few more references in this answer: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/16915/46.

Comment: @Alvin, highlighted(green) items using most of my project references.

Answer (score 1):

**Please update Editor.Config dependency reference namespaces as per sdl web 8.1**

```
 <!-- <cfg:dependencies>
          <cfg:dependency>SDL.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
          <cfg:dependency>SDL.Web.UI.Editors.CME.CommandSets.All</cfg:dependency>
          <!--<cfg:dependency>Example.UiCoreService.Editor.Base</cfg:dependency> -->
 <!-- </cfg:dependencies> -->
```

**Update js the Reference namespaces.
**/Scripts/ExtendedPage.js
/Scripts/ExtendedComponent.js****

```
Tridion.Type.registerNamespace("TEST.Tridion.RTFExtensions");
Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "TEST.Tridion.RTFExtensions.ComponentEx");
```